# How to check identical array in most efficient way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I want to check if the two arrays are identical
(not content wise, but in exact order).

For example:

```
 array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
 array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
 array3 = [3,5,1,2,4]
```

Array 1 and 2 are identical but 3 is not.

Is there a good way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You might want to check [Compare two Arrays Javascript - Associative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107237/compare-two-arrays-javascript-associative)

Comment: i think some of the answers are going for "lines of code" efficiency, like larry k, while others are going for speed of execution efficiency.  sadly, you didn't state which you were looking for :)

Comment: @koopajah Didn't vote to close as the difference is that the older question is set comparison and this is set comparison along with order of contents.  So set a == b && a set is in the same order as b.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

So, what's wrong with checking each element iteratively?

```
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's safest, fastest, more flexible, always accurate, and actually *more* "elegant" that the `array.join()` approach -- once the function is defined.  It's also less memory intensive, if that becomes an issue.

Comment: Nice approach. There is a little issue: The variable i should go from arr1.length - 1 to 0, not from arr1.length to 0.

Comment: @mimarcel: The `i--` statement evaluates once before the iteration starts.

Comment: @palswim you are right! i dind't realise the ``i--`` has a double trick. :)

Comment: There's actually a **bug** when this function deals with nested arrays:

`arraysEqual( [[1],[2,3]], [[1],[2,3]] )` will return false

Comment: I think it will only work in shorted array. in case unsorted array it will not work.

Comment: @Richard: This answer provides a shallow check algorithm. Your comment begs the question about the nature of equality. Two arrays with the same contents are not equal in Javascript, so are the contents of `[[1],[2,3]]` and `[[1],[2,3]]` equal? No, because `[1]` is not equal to `[1]` (assuming you have instantiated those arrays separately).

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: This will only work on "sorted" arrays because [the question asked for equality in order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4025893/393280), not just isomorphism.

Answer (score 48):

You could compare String representations so:

```
array1.toString() == array2.toString()
array1.toString() !== array3.toString()
```

but that would also make

```
array4 = ['1',2,3,4,5]
```

equal to array1 if that matters to you

Comment: This is plain wrong as it seem to suggest that [ 1, 2 ] equals [ '1,2' ] and also equals [ 1, '2' ]..... etc. etc.

Comment: It overlooked the type of each item.

Comment: Just ran some quick tests and a `for` loop is much, *MUCH* faster than the `toString` method. In my tests, the worst-case scenario for the `for` loop was being `20x` faster. The worst case was the `for` loop being `80x` faster. So basically don't ever use this method, it's both wrong and slow :).

Comment: Thanks, could be useful to quickly test 2 arrays and remain readable even if it's not THE perfect way to do it ;)

Comment: Or  
`array1.join() == array3.join();`  but this does not check for type

Comment: Not the ideal solution, but works when you know the type is correct, or (in my case) you WANT the arrays to match even when the object types are different.

Comment: actually this was useful to me as i am guaranteed to compare the same types. Looks  light