# Compare two diff array with same size

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have a simple application in which I want compare two arrays.

```
function check() {
    var Array1 = value.length;
    var Array2 = selected_value.length;
    alert(Array1 + "," + Array2);
    for (var i = 0; i < Array1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < Array2; j++) {
            if (value[i] == selected_value[j]) {
                alert("both div are same");
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

my arrays have  4 elements each but the `if` condition is not satisfied.

Comment: In future, please consider spending more time formatting your question. Making it look like you've spent more than 4 seconds writing your question through correct indentation and proper spelling will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Think of an algorithm to do the task. What you have checks for each (sic!) combination of values whether they are the same, and for each equal pair it alerts "both div are same".

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/BBedy/

Comment: actually my one array contain value which I retrive from jsonobject but I stored whole value inside array

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check identical array in most efficient way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025893/how-to-check-identical-array-in-most-efficient-way)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is function, with which you can compare two arrays

```
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025958/295264)

You can check if array return false, like this

```
if(!arrayEqual(arr1,arr2)) {
   // false
}
```

Comment: your code is working Starvx I am new in javascript if suppose If that array return false then how to check it....I know this question is worthless but can you help me

Comment: @Pranali, I just gave you a way to check false, didn't I?

Comment: I am sry i just saw ur comment but yor code returning true if both array similar or different

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10169/discussion-between-pranali-and-starx)

Comment: @Pranali, It will return true, if both are similar

Comment: in if condition it may be like this ( if(arr1[i] != arr2[i])
)

Comment: @Pranali, I dont understand, those are not array, they are items in array

Answer (score 0):

try to view yout values. before `if` write console.log( value[i], selected_valuw[j]) and check whether they are alike

Comment: i check that when this values are not similar then also I got true value