# Compare JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why [] == [] is false in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703222/why-is-false-in-javascript)

I would like to ask about strange thing, i.e.:

```
var x = "pl";
var y = ["pl"];
[x] == y; // false - why?
x == y; // true - how ? 
x === y; // false - okay
```

Can some one explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is false because you're comparing two arrays (which are objects) - a comparison which will always be false unless the objects are actually *the same object*, **or** if the objects are coerced to a different type of value like in the second comparison.

In the second comparison, y is coerced to be a string value, and then found to be equal to `"pl"`.

For instance, this code:

```
["pl"] + "foo" → "plfoo"
```

Incidentally, this is why you should always use `===` instead of `==` - it doesn't result in any surprising coercions. That's why the third comparison is false.

Comment: ok then explain this:  ["hello", " john"] == "hello, john" // true

Comment: `[x] == y` does a shallow comparison, and since the two do not refer to the same array, it returns false.

Comment: @cojack `['a', 'b', 'c'].toString()` → `'a,b,c'`

Answer (score 2):

**Array to Array (abstract equality comparison)**

```
[x] == y; // false - why?
```

`[x]` and `y` do not refer to the same object. [Arrays](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) are [objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1) and the [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1) operator tests that they are the *same* object, not simply two objects having identical values for all properties. In order to determine object-equality in *that* way, you'll have to manually enumerate the properties of each object and test each value.

According to [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) used by [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1):

> Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

**String to Array (abstract equality comparison)**

```
x == y; // true - how ? oO
```

`y`, an array, is coerced into a string because you used [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1) when comparing it to `x`, a string.

According to [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) used by [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1):

> If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return
>   the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

**String to Array (strict equality comparison)**

```
x === y; // fasle - okey
```

[`===`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4), unlike [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1), will *not* coerce `y` into a string... so, you're comparing a string to an object.

According to [The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) used by [`===`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4):

> If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
[x] == y;
```

['pl'] == ['p1'] - comparing refs on 2 different arrays in memory

```
x == y;
```

The same as "pl" == ["p1"].toString(). JS convert the second argument to the string because the first one is also string