# Why is this simple JSON.parse JavaScript code failing?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to understand why this simple code is saying false instead of true.

```
let test1 = JSON.parse("[]");
let test2 = JSON.parse("[]");

console.log(test1 == test2);
```

Surely this code should be true but I always get it saying false. Whats the issue?

Thanks

Comment: It is working perfectly, `[] === []` and `[] == []` are false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703222/why-is-false-in-javascript

Comment: Objects are equal by reference, [] is a new object with a new reference, the right hand [] is also a brand new object with a new reference, so they are not equal..