# Is there a way to check if two arrays have the same elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let say I have 2 arrays

```
firstArray  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
secondArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
```

I want to know if they contain the same elements, while order is not important. I know I can write a function to sort them and then loop through them to check, but is there a pre-built function for this? (not only Vanilla JS, other javascript library is also okay)

Comment: all elements are unique in the array??

Comment: @Pratik No, comparing the two arrays.

Comment: Yes for my case, but would be better if it can handle duplicated elements too.

Comment: No, there is nothing exactly what you want. But you can do it pragmatically.

Comment: Then you have to write manually and chek all cases.

Comment: try with this library: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: You could look at http://underscorejs.org/#difference if an empty array is returned then the arrays were the same.

Comment: Did you see this question and its answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025893/how-to-check-identical-array-in-most-efficient-way

Comment: @MattSaw `difference` will not work. Try `[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: You can check each element iteratively, but then you'd have to create temporary arrays and sort them first.

Comment: @thefourtheye In that case [4] is returned, meaning the contents was not the same?

Comment: @MattSaw Are sure? Try this `console.log(_.difference([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]));` you will get an empty array. I think you tried it like this `console.log(_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]));`

Comment: @thefourtheye you are indeed correct! I did not fully understand that method's usage.

Comment: I updated my answer to correct the issue of `1` and `"1"` returning as a match due to the use of the `sort` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using jQuery**

You can compare the two arrays using `jQuery`:

```
// example arrays:
var firstArray  = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var secondArray = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ];

// compare arrays:
var isSameSet = function( arr1, arr2 ) {
  return  $( arr1 ).not( arr2 ).length === 0 && $( arr2 ).not( arr1 ).length === 0;  
}

// get comparison result as boolean:
var result = isSameSet( firstArray, secondArray );
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/7b1n4mjk/)

See this question [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Don't like the name isIdentical as identical should include order too, but the way of doing is great.

Comment: @user1273587 Thanks. What variable name would you use here? I did consider this for a few moments but had no better alternative. Update welcome!

Comment: How about sameSet() ?

Comment: dublicate values also alerts true.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have:

```
const xs = [1,2,3];
const ys = [3,2,1];
```

This *seems* to work:

```
xs.every(x => ys.includes(x));
//=> true
```

But it gives you false positives:

```
const xs = [2,2,2];
const ys = [1,2,3];

xs.every(x => ys.includes(x));
//=> true

// But…
ys.every(y => xs.includes(y));
//=> false
```

Another example:

```
const xs = [2];
const ys = [1,2,3];

xs.every(x => ys.includes(x));
//=> true

// But…
ys.every(y => xs.includes(y));
//=> false
```

We could compare the size of both arrays and bail out quickly but technically these two arrays do contain the same elements:

```
const xs = [2];
const ys = [2,2,2];

ys.every(y => xs.includes(y));
//=> true

xs.every(x => ys.includes(x));
//=> true
```

The way I would answer this question is by computing the set of unique values for both arrays.

```
const similar = (xs, ys) => {
  const xsu = [...new Set(xs).values()]; // unique values of xs
  const ysu = [...new Set(ys).values()]; // unique values of ys
  return xsu.length != ysu.length ? false : xsu.every(x => ysu.includes(x));
}

similar([1,2,3],[3,2,1]);
//=> true

similar([2,2,2],[3,2,1]);
//=> false

similar([2],[3,2,1]);
//=> false

similar([2],[2,2,2]);
//=> true

similar([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
//=> false
```

Comment: Is it ok that `similar( [1,1,2,3], [1,2,2,3] );` returns `true`? If the expectation is that the elements can be different orders, but otherwise match one-for-one, then this would be an unexpected result.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Vanilla JavaScript**

Supported in all modern browsers you can use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

**ECMAScript 2016**

```js
let firstArray  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let secondArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let Equals = firstArray.every((item)=>secondArray.includes(item))
alert("Equals? " + Equals)
```

**Internet Explorer Support**

Internet Explorer does not have access to [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If you need it to run in Internet Explorer you can use indexOf

```js
let firstArray  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let secondArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let Equals = firstArray.every(function (item){return secondArray.indexOf(item) > -1})
alert("Equals? " + Equals)
```

This will iterate through every item in firstArray and check if the value is contained within secondArray, and return true only if the function returns true for Every item

*Do note that the given function will work for this question, But is Non Recursive and only works with primitive types on two Flat arrays, If you want to compare non-primitives you will need to modify the compare function to compare your Object structure*

Comment: ES2016 example still reports true if secondArray has additional values. Adding a check for firstArray.length === secondArray.length should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is an [`Array.sort()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method in JavaScript, and for comparing the (sorted) arrays, I think it's best to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript), as it is has a really good answer.

Especially note that comparing arrays as strings (e.g. by `JSON.stringify`) is a **very bad** idea, as values like `"2,3"` might break such a check.

Comment: Array.sort() modifies the actual array. It's worth cloning the array, then sorting it, and then checking each element iteratively.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working implementation using Vanilla JS:

```
function haveMatchingElements(firstArray, secondArray) {
    var stringsInFirstArray = parse(firstArray, 'string'),
        stringsInSecondArray = parse(secondArray, 'string'),
        numbersInFirstArray = parse(firstArray, 'number'),
        numbersInSecondArray = parse(secondArray, 'number'),
        stringResults = compare(stringsInFirstArray, stringsInSecondArray),
        numberResults = compare(numbersInFirstArray, numbersInSecondArray);

    if (stringResults && numberResults) {
        return true;
    } return false;

    function parse(array, type) {
        var arr = [];
        arr = array.sort().filter(function(index) {
            if (typeof index == type)
                return index;
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function compare(firstArray, secondArray) {
        if (firstArray.length !== secondArray.length)
            return false;
        for (var i = firstArray.length; i--;) {
            if (firstArray[i] !== secondArray[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This parses strings an numbers into different arrays and checks them separately. That will correct the issue of `1` and `"1"` matching as `true` due to the implicit type conversion caused by the `sort` function.

The implementation is simple:

```
var arr1 = ['1', 1];
var arr2 = [1, '1'];

var results = haveMatchingElements(arr1, arr2);
console.log(results); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can verify if two arrays have exactly the same elements and in the same order in ES6:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 7, 9];
const array2 = [2, 1, 3]

const arraysWithSameValuesAndOrder = (array1, array2) => {
    return array1.every((item) => array1.indexOf(item) === array2.indexOf(item)) && Boolean(array1.length === array2.length)
  }

const res = arraysWithSameValuesAndOrder(array1, array2)
console.log('res', res) FALSE
```

Comment: OP asked about a method where you compare two arrays which have the same elements but in DIFFERENT ORDER.

Comment: because the point of the question is that it should not be compared whether they are in the same order or not but your function is literally called "arraysWithSaveValuesAndOrder"

Answer (score -2):

Not in Vanila Javascript but in Angular there is option to match two objects.

```
angular.equals([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

Determines if two objects or two values are equivalent. Supports value types, regular expressions, arrays and objects.

See if this could help you.

```js
alert("Match result of [1,2,3] &  [1,2,3] is "+angular.equals([1,2,3],[1,2,3]));

alert("Match result of [1,4,3] &  [1,2,3] is "+angular.equals([1,4,3],[1,2,3]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Click on Run Code snippet. If this solves your need please mark it as as Answer :)

In case order is not important and array is of number type.

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3];
var a2 = [2, 1, 3];
//In case order is not important and array is of number type.
alert(eval(JSON.stringify(a1).replace(/,/g, "+").replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "")) === eval(JSON.stringify(a2).replace(/,/g, "+").replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "")));
```

Comment: Try `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 2, 1]`. OP wants `true` for this case.

Comment: in that case you can directly go for plain Javascript code.                      var a1 = [1, 2, 3];
        var a2 = [2, 1, 3];
        alert(eval(JSON.stringify(a1).replace(/,/g, "+").replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "")) === eval(JSON.stringify(a2).replace(/,/g, "+").replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "")));

Comment: Comparing an array by string is a poor way. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript