# for loop without condition checking

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025958/7844349), I am not able to grasp the concept used for the 'for loop'

Generally, syntax of for loop is `for(assign value, check condition, increment){}`
They have used the for loop but there is no condition checking, how does this work?

```
for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Above code is checking if any 2 values are different, the array is not identical and breaks the loop using `return false`

Comment: because there is explicitly condition checking inside the for loop. If the condition gets false then it will return false.

Comment: you could use array function like `Array#filter` it's helpful to find the match

Comment: @prasad No. Filter will loop till end. This is the best solution

Comment: What I meant was, is it okay to use for loop without the second condtion - should we not write - for(var i = arr1.length;" leave this blank";i--;){}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, it's

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

where all three expressions are *optional*.

In this case, `i--` **is** a condition, when it reaches `0` it's falsy, and the loop stops.
The `"final-expression"` is the one not used here.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

The `for` statement sets the value of `i` to a positive integer, then on each iteration it evaluates the condition, effectively decrementing `i` until it reaches a number that is falsy, which happens when `i` reaches zero.

---

Here's some other examples of how to skip expressions in a `for` loop

Skipping the initialization

```js
var i = 0;
for (; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Skipping the condition

```js
for (var i = 0;; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   if (i > 3) break;
}
```

Skipping **everything**

```js
var i = 0;

for (;;) {
  if (i > 4) break;
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: @DeepikaRao They're all technically optional depending on what you want to do. `for (;;);` will compile, but probably won't be something you want

Answer (score 0):

See the code carefully

```
for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
        return false;
}
```

Whenever the browser encounters the `return` statement the control is moved outside the `for` loop and even outside the function containing this `for` loop. So, the loops breaks without having a condition when the condition `arr1[i] !== arr2[i]` is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

All the three arguments in a for loop is optional.

Here the loop iterates with i value changing from arr1.length -> 1.
Decrementing i is done in the second argument itself.
Since the second argument is for condition checking it will return a falsy value when i becomes zero, and the iteration stops.
If the arrays don't match the loop will return false in the middle.